# Caching All Images of a folder using html 5

Tags: html5-appcache

I am creating an html 5 offline web application and i want to  load all images from a specified folder in the server to the browser cache using html 5 cache manifest file before the first page loads.So that after the first page loads,if the internet connection goes,i can see the web application.I have searched google for an answer and it shows me to list all images in the server folder one by one in the manifest file.But that will not be possible because the website has an admin panel,using that we can upload more images.So i should have to make the cache mainifest file with some thing like this

```
 host/images/*
```

But while googling,I can understand that that is not possible.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got an answer for my problem.I can understand that it is not possible to use html5 cachemanifest for phonegap applications.I just had a sample build in which all images are listed in the cache manifest file and nothing was cached as i expected.Then i understand that for using cache manifest,The page i am using the images,the images and the cache manifest file should be in the same domain.So that is not possible.Then i find that i can cache things in the DOM.